# Number of solutions for quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Let $n, m, k \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $p \in \mathbb{P}$ be an odd prime with gcd$(n, p) =1$. How would one approach proving:

$$
\#\{x \in \mathbb{F}_p\,\vert\ nx^2 + mx + k \equiv 0 \pmod{p}\} = 1 + \frac{n^2 - 4mk}{p}
$$

How many solutions are there for when gcd$(n, p)  \neq 1$?

I know about quadratic reciprocity, but am stuck on how to apply it in a useful way here.

Comment: the gcd cannot be $0$. Perhaps you meant $\gcd(n,p)=1$?

Comment: @Mastrem Thank you for pointing out my typo!

Comment: You're missing brackets around your Legendre-symbol there